# Website Search Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search

How does the search algorithm on stackoverflow work? I need to implement a search functionality in one of my web sites.

Comment: Please don't take SO as something to emulate - when it comes to searching, it is one of the worst sites I have ever used.

Comment: The answer is: badly.  Most of the time I get better results searching SO with google.  Btw this question is probably going to be closed soon.

Comment: See this http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/stack-overflow-search-now-51-less-crappy/ fro the explanation of the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into Full Text Search:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-text_search

Answer (score 2):

Not very well.  If you need your site searchable, try adding a Google search box through Adsense (and setting up a sitemap).

Comment: definitely outsource this to Google. It's essentially what we do, since 90% of our traffic is from Google.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Full text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

and as stackoverflow saying:

- You're browsing through questions matching search terms
  search stackoverflow
- Search within specific tags by adding them in brackets, like [tag] or [tag-2].
- Enclose your search in "quotes" to match a phrase.
- You can narrow your search by using the ~ (near) and - (not) operators before words.*

Answer (score 0):

I believe they use the [Full Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) capabilities of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting SQL Server assumes thats the db backend, better to use [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) or if you dont want to use java there's [.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/lucene.net.html), [C](http://lucene.apache.org/lucy/) and [Ruby](http://ferret.davebalmain.com/trac/) ports of the lucene.

Actually i wouldn't be surprised if SO is [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/lucene.net.html) based.